# Select a field that is in group by using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to select a field that is part of group by in LINQ?

eg.:

```
var result =   from a in table
           where Date >= DataStart && Date <= DataStop
           group a by a.Field2 into b
           select new
               {
                   AA = b.Sum(x => x.Total),
                   BB = a.Field2
               };
```

Comment: What is `table`? Also, what are `Date`, `DataStart` and `DataStop`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're grouping by `Field2`, `Field2` is the key of the group, so you can use `b.Key`

```
var result =   from a in table
               where a.Date >= DataStart && a.Date <= DataStop
               group a by a.Field2 into b
               select new
               {
                   AA = b.Sum(x => x.Total),
                   BB = b.Key
               };
```